# Comprimir array com valores iguais C

Tags: c

O problema consiste no seguinte:
Fazer um algoritmo que lê um vetor A[10].
Após, retire os elementos em duplicata compactando o vetor A. 
Por fim inserir o valor zero nos últimos elementos. 
Mostre o vetor A atualizado.

Mas por fim ele não executa, da a impressao, pois nao faz nada e nao imprime o novo vetor em tela.

segue codigo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
Fazer um algoritmo que lê um vetor A[10].
Após, retire os elementos em duplicata compactando o vetor A. 
Por fim inserir o valor zero nos últimos elementos. 
Mostre o vetor A atualizado.
*/

int main(void)
{
// declara variaveis
    //declara vetor unico
    int vet[9];
    //declara contador referente a vetor
    int count;
    //variavel auxiliar zero_final
    int zf;
    //variavel recebimento, recebe valores para testalos com o resto do array
    int rec;
    //variavel incremento auxiliar
    int i;
    //variavel compressao de array
    int comp;



    //variavel 'zf' (zero_final) decrementa valores para incluir zeros no final do vetor
    zf=10;

    /*cabeçalho inicial*/

    //entra com valores
    puts("\t*---------------------------*");
    puts("\t| <<< ENTRE COM VALORES >>> |");
    puts("\t*---------------------------*");
    for(count;count<=9;count++)
        scanf("%i",&vet[count]);    
    count=0;
    //exibe valores ordenados em tela
    for(count;count<=9;count++)
        printf("\t VETOR[%i] = %i\n",count,vet[count]);     
    /*cabeçalho inicial*/

    i=0;
    for(count=0;count<=9;count++)
    {
        rec=vet[count];
        while(i!=9)
        {
            if(rec==vet[count])
            {
                zf--;
                comp=count;
            }
            for(;count<=9;count++)
            {
                vet[count]=vet[count++];
            }
            count=comp;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //inclui valor zero no fim do array
    for(;count<=zf;count++)
    {
        vet[count]=0;
    }   
    //imprime array em tela
    for(count;count<=9;count++)
        printf("\t VETOR[%i] = %i\n",count,vet[count]); 

    printf(" -- PRESSIONE ALGO --");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aqui rodou e a saída foi exatamente o vetor de entrada: http://ideone.com/VWBka4

Comment: Inicialize `count` antes do primeiro laço `for`. Fazendo isso, o resultado será o que o @AndersonCarlosWoss citou.

Comment: @mercador nao foi feito isso ja?

Comment: ta mas e na verdade teria que fazer o que o enunciado pede, sera que tem como me ajudar a respeito?

Comment: @AGenaro não foi feito, você apenas declarou a variável. Um outro ponto é que seu vetor tem tamanho `9`, sendo que seu enunciado diz precisar de um com tamanho `10`.

Comment: O problema da falta de inicialização também ocorre com a variável `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Agenaro, como apontado nos comentários, seu primeiro problema está na inicialização da variavel comp antes dos comandos for. Resolvendo isso, aparece um problema de lógica na hora de descobrir as variaveis repetidas. Corrigi o problema do comp e reescrevi a busca por elementos iguais. veja abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
Fazer um algoritmo que lê um vetor A[10].
Após, retire os elementos em duplicata compactando o vetor A. 
Por fim inserir o valor zero nos últimos elementos.  
Mostre o vetor A atualizado.
*/

int main(void)
{
// declara variaveis
//declara vetor unico
int vet[9];
//declara contador referente a vetor
int count;
//variavel auxiliar zero_final
int zf;
//variavel recebimento, recebe valores para testalos com o resto do array
int rec;
//variavel incremento auxiliar
int comp;
//variavel auxiliar no for


//variavel 'zf' (zero_final) decrementa valores para incluir zeros no final do vetor
zf=10;

/*cabeçalho inicial*/

//entra com valores
puts("\t*---------------------------*");
puts("\t| <<< ENTRE COM VALORES >>> |");
puts("\t*---------------------------*");
for(count = 0;count<=9;count++){
    scanf("%i",&vet[count]);
}

for(count = 0, comp = 9; count <= comp; count++){ //Um for que compara a atual posição com todas as seguintes
    for(rec = count + 1; rec <= comp; rec++){
        if(vet[count] == vet[rec]){ //se houver uma repetição
            /*Por questão de eficiencia, troca-se o valor repetido pelo ultimo, decrementa o tamanho do comprimento "real" do vetor*/
            vet[rec] = vet[comp--];
            rec--;//caso a ultima posição seja repetida
        }
    }

}

//inclui valor zero no fim do array
for(count = comp + 1; count < zf; count++)
{
    vet[count]=0;
}   

//imprime array em tela
for(count = 0; count<=9;count++)
    printf("\t VETOR[%i] = %i\n",count,vet[count]); 

printf(" -- PRESSIONE ALGO --\n");
getchar();
return 0;
```

}